# How to parse escaped string using `c_escape_ch_p` from boost::spirit?

Tags: boost, escaping, boost-spirit

I'm trying to use `c_escape_ch_p` (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/escape_char.hpp%20here)) from `boost::spirit` to parse an escaped `C++` string. But I'm getting a compiler error. Here is my code:

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/escape_char.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/confix.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace client {
  namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
  namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

  template <typename Iterator>
  bool parse(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    using qi::char_;
    qi::rule< Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type > text;

    using namespace boost::spirit::classic;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> myword2 =
      confix_p('"', *c_escape_ch_p, '"') ; // ERROR!   
    text = myword2;

    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(first, last, text, ascii::space);
    if (first != last)
      return false;
    return r;
  }
}

int main () {
  std::string s = "\"foo\"";
  bool ok = client::parse(s.begin(), s.end());
  std::cout << "OK? " << (ok ? "y" : "n") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler error is a failed static assert instantiated from the line with `confix`:

```
    // Report invalid expression error as early as possible.                                                            
    // If you got an error_invalid_expression error message here,                                                       
    // then the expression (expr) is not a valid spirit qi expression.                                                  
    BOOST_SPIRIT_ASSERT_MATCH(qi::domain, Expr);
```

So, it says it's not a valid expression. How is it used correctly?

P.S.: I'm using Boost 1.45.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to combine classic (old, V1, ...) boost::spirit::classic and (new, V2) boost::spirit::qi.

This is not going to work. The newer stuff is a complete, and incompatible, rewrite. See the 'Porting from Spirit 1.8.x' notes in the documentation.
As for the question on how to parse escaped C/C++ strings using boost::spirit::qi, the following article will be helpful:

[Parsing Escaped String Input Using Spirit.Qi](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/parsing-escaped-string-input-using-spirit-qi/)